# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am using `Facebooks Javascript API` to import to my website the `albums` and `photos` of a Facebook page.

My javascript code looks like this :

```
<script>
        var albumPhotos = new Array();
        var albumThumbnails = new Array();
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK 
            FB.init({
                appId      : '5698434687426',                    // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'channel.html',                       // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
            });

            // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
            FB.api('1607099163/albums', function(response) {
                if(!response || response.error) {
                    // render error
                    alert("Noo!!");
                } else {
                    // render photos
                    for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){  
                        (function (i) {
                            var albumName = response.data[i].name;
                            var albumCover = response.data[i].cover_photo;
                            var albumId = response.data[i].id;
                            var numberOfPhotos = response.data[i].count

                            FB.api(albumId + "/photos", function(response) {
                                if(!response || response.error) {
                                    // render error
                                    alert("Noo!!");
                                } else {
                                    for(var k=0; k<numberOfPhotos; k++){
                                         albumThumbnails[i][k] = response.data[k].picture;
                                         albumPhotos[i][k] = response.data[k].source;
                                    }
                                }
                            }); 


                            console.log(albumName);
                            FB.api( albumCover, function(response) {
                                if(!response || response.error) {
                                    // render error
                                    alert("Noo!!");
                                } else {
                                    // render photos
                                    $(".albums").append('<li>'+
                                        '<a href="#Gallery' + i + '"' + 'data-transition="slidedown">'+
                                        '<img src= "' + response.picture + '"  />'+
                                         '<h2>' + albumName + '</h2>'+
                                         '<p>' + "Number of Photos:  " + numberOfPhotos +'</p>'+
                                         '</a>'+
                                         '</li>')
                                    .listview('refresh');

                                    $("#home").after('<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id=Gallery'+ i +
                                        ' class="gallery-page"> ' +
                                        ' <div data-role="header"></div> ' + ' <div data-role="content"> ' +
                                        ' <ul class="gallery"></ul> ' + ' </div> ' +
                                        ' </div> ');


                                }
                            }); 
                        })(i);                                      
                    } //end of for loop
                }
            });

        };
```

As you can see in the beginning i use the API to get information about the `albums` of the specific page :  `FB.api('169070991963/albums', function(response) {...}`

Everything works as expected and i can get information as `albumNames , albumCovers , albumIds` etc .

Now for every album that i import , i want to have an array where i will save all of its pictures and thumbnails. For this reason i make another API call , `FB.api(albumId + "/photos", function(response) {}` .

I process the response like this :

```
for(var k=0; k<numberOfPhotos; k++){
              albumThumbnails[i][k] = response.data[k].picture;
              albumPhotos[i][k] = response.data[k].source;
                                   }
```

At this point though i get the error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

I cant understand what is undefined though... Any idea on this  ?

*By the way the next API call that i make `FB.api( albumCover, function(response) {..}` to get the cover photos of the albums and create a jquery mobile listView , works too.

### EDIT

---

The answer provided below solved the 2-dimensional table problem.

However now the error is : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined`

### EDIT2

---

I am experiencing the same issue later in the code so i am making this EDIT. The code now looks as suggested like this :

```
<script>
        var albumPhotos = new Array();
        var albumThumbnails = new Array();
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK 
            FB.init({
                appId      : '564984346887426',                    // App ID from the app dashboard
                channelUrl : 'channel.html',                       // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
            });

            // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
            FB.api('169070991963/albums', function(response) {
                if(!response || response.error) {
                    // render error
                    alert("Noo!!");
                } else {
                    // render photos
                    for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){  
                        (function (i) {
                            var albumName = response.data[i].name;
                            var albumCover = response.data[i].cover_photo;
                            var albumId = response.data[i].id;
                            var numberOfPhotos = response.data[i].count;

                            FB.api(albumId + "/photos", function(response) {
                                if(!response || response.error) {
                                    // render error
                                    alert("Noo!!");
                                } else {
                                    for(var k=0; k<response.data.length; k++){ 
                                         albumThumbnails[i] =  albumThumbnails[i]||{};
                                         albumThumbnails[i][k] = response.data[k].picture;
                                         albumPhotos[i] = albumPhotos[i] || {};
                                         albumPhotos[i][k] = response.data[k].source;
                                    }
                                }
                            }); 

                            console.log(albumName);
                            FB.api( albumCover, function(response) {
                                if(!response || response.error) {
                                    // render error
                                    alert("Noo!!");
                                } else {
                                    // render photos
                                    $(".albums").append('<li>'+
                                        '<a href="#Gallery' + i + '"' + 'data-transition="slidedown">'+
                                        '<img src= "' + response.picture + '"  />'+
                                         '<h2>' + albumName + '</h2>'+
                                         '<p>' + "Number of Photos:  " + numberOfPhotos +'</p>'+
                                         '</a>'+
                                         '</li>')
                                    .listview('refresh');

                                    $("#home").after('<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id=Gallery'+ i +
                                        ' class="gallery-page"> ' +
                                        ' <div data-role="header"><h1>Gallery</h1></div> ' + ' <div data-role="content"> ' +
                                        ' <ul class="gallery"></ul> ' + ' </div> ' +
                                        ' </div> ');

                                    for(var x=0; x < albumPhotos[i].length; x++)
                                        $('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').append('<li><a href="' + albumPhotos[i][x] + '" rel="external"><img src="' +  albumThumbnails[i][x] + '" /></a></li>');

                                }
                            }); 
                        })(i);                                      
                    } //end of for loop
                console.log(albumPhotos);
                console.log(albumThumbnails);
                }
            });

        };
```

I added this piece of code as you see :

```
for(var x=0; x < albumPhotos[i].length; x++)
            $('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery').append('<li><a href="' + albumPhotos[i][x] + '" rel="external"><img src="' +  albumThumbnails[i][x] + '" /></a></li>');
```

Every row in the 2dimensional table `albumPhotos` is an album and every column is a photo inside this album. With the `for` loop above i tried to create a list of Galleries that every Gallery has an album with all its photos.

Again i get the error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined 
.
.
.
```

Why do i get this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `albumThumbnails` and `albumPhotos` as empty arrays, and in the loop you are trying to add values into the array.

let us take the case where `i = 0` your array `albumThumbnails` has a length of `0` that means `albumThumbnails[0]` is undefined, then you are trying to set `albumThumbnails[0][0]` which is giving the error.

The solution here is to first create an empty object at the index `i` if required then set its property

Looks like you are trying to create the object here

```
for(var k=0; k<numberOfPhotos && k < response.data.length; k++){
    albumThumbnails[i] =  albumThumbnails[i]||{};
    albumThumbnails[i][k] = response.data[k].picture;
    albumPhotos[i] = albumPhotos[i] || {};
    albumPhotos[i][k] = response.data[k].source;
}
```

Comment: Yeap you were right but now i get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined. Actually this error i was getting from the beginning before i try to complex things with the 2 dimensional tables.

Comment: it is because response.data.length < numberOfPhotos

Comment: Hmm yes thats correct. But why is it causing a problem here? response.data.length gives me the number of the different albums. numberOfPhotos gives me the number of photos inside each album. Why are you comparing these 2 things?

Comment: @JohnyJaz actually there is no need to test `k<numberOfPhotos`. you need to test only for `k < response.data.length`

Comment: yes it works. However i cant understand why the numberOfPhotos was not working. Supposedly is the same number no?

Comment: @JohnyJaz I haven't used the FB api so don't know the data structure used here, but in terms of array usage it can be different

Comment: Anyway i ll look more into it. Thank you very much , you ve been more than helpful :D

Comment: @JohnyJaz you can print the values using console.log and see the results

Comment: Sir could you please check my EDIT2 for a new problem i encountered on this one? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnyJaz It will be better if you can post it as a new question instead of editing an existing question

Comment: I would post it , but it would be the same question again. I ve been told to avoid that and if a question is in a context of a question i just asked maybe is better to edit. What do you think?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32398/discussion-between-johny-jaz-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: Do you also think that the way i am declaring my 2dimensional arrays is correct? I just declare them as simple as this as u see : var albumPhotos = new Array();
        var albumThumbnails = new Array();